# Does iOS consider the UI is for LTR languages even if the localization development language is RTL for example arabic?

Tags: ios, localization, uistoryboard, xib, uilocalizedcollation

I have a legacy iOS application designed using nib files and the UI alignment  of the application is designed for arabic (Right-to-Left), then I try to add English localization to the nib files I do the following

1. I added "Localizations" key the .plist file of the project as Array and then I added the following items under "Localizations"  (item0 : English, item1: Arabic)
2. I added "Localization native development region" set its value to "ar".
3. Then I opened the project.pbxproj and change the value of "developmentRegion"   "developmentRegion = ar;"

I get the following result as in the image

[image]

The problem is when set the language of the applications to Arabic (RTL alignment) , iOS mirror the views from RTL(Right-to-Left) to LTR(Left-to-Right), I guess that iOS always consider UI for Left-to-Right languages and mirrors the views for RTL even if the native development languages is RTL language.

the question is does iOS consider the UI is for LTR languages even if the localization development language is RTL for example arabic ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Regardless of your development language, Interface Builder currently displays UI as if it were to be shown in an LTR language.

Comment: thank you so much for answer, but is there any way to force Interface Builder displays UI in a RTL languages ?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. You can preview RTL display using the [Assistant Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Art/assistant_jump_bar_preview_2x.png), but this is only a preview. I would suggest filing an enhancement request to Apple at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I've the same issue for now. Did you find any way to fix it?

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find a way to do this
but you have to build UI for LTR first and then localize the UI for RTL